# tomcat DNS forwarding with multiple applications

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, forwarding, cloaking

I recently installed business objects software on tomcat 6. I have 2 domains - domain1 and domain2. This software allows access to two of its applications via these URLS:

xxxxxhttp://myservername.domain1:8080/BO/APP1 and xxxxhttp://myservername.domain1:8080/BO/APP2

Instead of these urls, I would like the end users to access these apps via something like http://bobj.domain2.com:8080/BO/APP1 and http://bobj.domain2.com:8080/BO/APP2.

I cannot figure out how to accomplish that. I have looked into the option of http redirect (not good because the destination address shows up in the address bar), domain forwarding (not sure if it would work with multiple applications and forwarding from one domain to another) and also using apache tomcat with mod_jk by using virtual hosts (not sure if it is possible when forwarding from one domain to a sub domain in another domain) ??

Experts, please advise as to what would be my best option and how to accomplish.

thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

There must be a DNS entry for bobj.domain2.com to point to your IP address. Then adding a ServerAlias directive to Apache should do the trick. You can also use wildcards, e.g. DNS entry for *.domain2.com, and ServerAlias *.domain2.com.

Comment: Dondi, Thanks for your reply. If i add the DNS entry for bobj.domain2.com to the server ip, wouldnt the server ip show up as the destination address in the address bar of the user ? Also, how would I add a server alias directive to apache ? can you shed some light on that ? Thanks

Comment: Also, I want the end users to be able to access 2 apps via different addresses: bobj.domain2.com/BO/APP1 and bobj.domain2.com/BO/APP2. How would server alias work in that case ?

Comment: For the first question, no, it would work like any domain. When you type in stackoverflow.com you do not see an IP address in the address bar do you? For the second question, if you have a VirtualHost in Apache for `myservername.domain1.com`, you would add a line `ServerAlias bobj2.domain2.com`, and also `UseCanonicalName Off`. The rest of the configuration (the two URLs for the APP1 and APP2) would be the same as the existing domain name.

Comment: Dondi, how does this plan sound then: 1) setup 2 DNS A records that forwards bobj1.domain2.com and bobj2.domain2.com to my server's ip address. Then install Apache. In apache, I create two virtual hosts for two sub domains - bobj1.domain2.com and bobj2.domain2.com. Then add two server aliases, 1 for each virtual host ?                                                                    1 more question: I already have my webapps installed on a tomcat instance. So now when I install and setup apache, do I need to redeploy my webapps to this apache tomcat ? Thanks